# Print browser page SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, printing, swt

I am developing a desktop application using SWT.I have embedded a browser in it.I want to add print and print preview functions to this app.I have searched for tutorials but dint find any except this http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/122978/ .But to understand this solution i need to know how to implement print fuction.Does anyone have any ideas?Iknow we can use browser.execute() to print but i dont want to use any other scripts.

Comment: Maybe this answer is a start? Not exactly a tutorial, but it looks like a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156231/print-using-swt-browser-widget

Comment: @Calon Ive seen that already.He uses a java script.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't read your last sentence thoroughly.

Comment: Eclipse help uses `Browser.execute` so I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: @greg-449 But the answer in the link i specified tells that there is a way to do using printer API of SWT

Comment: That is talking about ordinary SWT controls, the Browser is different.